# how to make a label or point in the repository

Tags: svn

I was looking for making a named 'revision' in the registry that might serve as the start of a branch or a point we can go back to where everything worked between us.

Using SVN

I am not able to find out how we can achieve this

Any idea how can we achieve this in Assembla .

thanks

Answer (score 2):

That is called a [tag](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.tags.html). There are plenty of guides on how to work with tags, which are basically names for a particular revision.